# DBX firmware update and corrupted bios

Tags: uefi, bios, secure-boot, firmware, boot-time

everyone,

Last week, I updated the DBX firmware to 371 from Ubuntu on Aspire A515-43. So, when I updated the dbx, my laptop froze (Ubuntu OS), which led me to perform a forced shutdown via the power button. So, now my Windows boot takes a long time, and I tried to perform a clean installation to Win11 and then Win10, but the issue was not resolved. Thus, the dbx update caused damage or corrugated my bios firmware (that was what I thought because my laptop was unable to boot, which led me to do a second force shutdown), affecting the boot time of Windows OS. So, can I reinstall bios (safe method) without losing my laptop? Or reinstall the same bios update (BIOS 1.12V) by Insyde h2offt? Or is there a way to view why the Windows system is delaying the boot process?

I thought this update would be for Ubuntu, not bios firmware update, which led me to trust it ️.

Thanks,